# GPUImage and Monotouch binding or alternative

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm currently using Monotouch for an iOS project and I need to make transformations on images (scale, filters, etc).

I've seen that GPUImage is a good native library for doing so. I've also seen on SO that some people tried to write the Monotouch binding of it.

Does anyone knows if we can find such project somewhere? It does not appear on the [official bindings repositories](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings), neither on Google, so it may not be done or released yet.

I would be pleased to help to make such binding, I just don't want to rewrite if it's already done.

Also, I can use another lib compatible with Monotouch (= with an existing binding). Do you have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Here you go. Why don't you create a github repo and share your additions with the rest of the world: http://sdrv.ms/10ngIal

Comment: @OliverWeichhold If you allow me I can add them to [monotouch-bindings repo on github](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings)

Comment: Thanks a lot @OliverWeichhold for sharing this with us, and thanks Saad Imran for adding it to the official binding repo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Olivier Weichold who gave us a link for a working version of a Monotouch binding of GPUImage.

As I had some time to work on it I started a first version on a [monotouch-bindings forked repository](https://github.com/pixelnest/monotouch-bindings) and I also made a pull request to the official repository so it may be official soon.

I wrote a little sample and the binding is working, it may just miss some features that can be easily added.

I will update the binding from the official repository as I will use it.

Comment: Very awesome! Will check this out.